# Create table in mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "****", line 17, in module
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE `Project1`(`Id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,`TERM` VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, `TYPE1` VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, `ACTION` VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, `CERTAINITY` DOUBLE(3) NOT NULL");
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL' at line 1")
```

line 1: import mysqldb as mdb

after rectifying the double problem,
I got a similar error, with the last sentence changed as
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")

the line to create tables was modified to
CREATE TABLE `Project1`(`Id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,`Term` VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, `Type1` VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, `Action` VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, `Certainity` DOUBLE(4,3) NOT NULL)

NEW PROBLEM,

I changed 'Certainity' to string

```
    File "/home/ankitaprasad/Ontology Project3/Stanford.py", line 57, in <module>
    cur.execute("""INSERT INT0 Project1(Term, Type1, Action, Certainity) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(term,type1,action,ab));
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
      _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Project1(Term, Type1, Action, Certainity) VALUES ('','','','0')' at line 1")
```

[Finished in 1.2s with exit code 1]

here ab=str(mod)

Comment: It simply means you have an error in your SQL syntax, not in your python code.  Run your SQL statement in the client and correct it to create your table properly.

Comment: How do i do it? running statement in client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your entire create statement formatted into this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Project1` (
    `Id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    `TERM` VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    `TYPE1` VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    `ACTION` VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    `CERTAINITY` DOUBLE(3) NOT NULL
```

See where you are missing the closing parentheses?  Fixing that, you still have a problem as [`DOUBLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) require *two* arguments, not one, so that is a syntax error for MySQL.  Please read the documentation and carefully look at what you wrote before asking questions and it will save you a lot of time, especially shortly before a deadline.

Comment: i modified double and the brackets were there but it didnt get printed here. the same error came again

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce, your changes results in a valid SQL statement and ran it without syntax errors from the mysql client.

Comment: No, you were write about the bracket. Thanks a tonne, I have another type error problem , should i post the problem, here itself ?

Comment: Try figuring out what's wrong yourself first, as normally these questions are normally not what stackoverflow is about - this is not a code correction service for minor typographical errors. If you can't figure out please format the code segments in your questions properly with indentation (4 spaces in front of each line) and ensure that it merits asking.

Comment: i sat on it for a lot of time trying to figure it out. Can you just help me this other one ? I'll indent it better with 4 spaces

Comment: You seriously can't tell the difference between `INT0` and `INTO`? (hint: one is a number and the other is a letter).

Comment: I searched through all the available links on google and stack overflow and i just didnt see it

Comment: Google (and StackOverflow) is not going to help you with simple typographical errors in general. As I said already, you have to be very careful with what you type when programming.